# Form Posting to Wrong Path Wrong Create Method Simple_Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

**2nd Update**

This is the code in my model

```
after_initialize :start_two_weeks


    def start_two_weeks
        @subscription = TrialSubscription.all 
        @subscription.manual_expiry_date = 
        @subscription.save
    end
```

How do you set the time dynamically from Time.now to Time.now - 2 weeks? 
Its a datetime field what is the value for a datetime field?
**More Update**
this means I didn't log out

```
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

I logged out and the user did get created but its through the registration controller.....

**Updated**
I just realized that the form is posting to /users. The registrations controller is inheritting from devise::registration

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-23 19:58:08 -0400
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8xhRi7TBEA+zXfmuzuJLqLjjo5JMkyEjUmgmRT6DsOQ=", "user"=>{"email"=>"helloworld@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4.1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

The form isn't posting to here

```
new_trial_subscription GET        /trial_subscriptions/new(.:format)                      trial_subscriptions#new

POST       /trial_subscriptions(.:format)                          trial_subscriptions#create
```

---

Ok I am trying to reproduce the stuff that I did in rails console to put them into the controllers.

I have two models

```
class TrialSubscription < ManualSubscription

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
    attr_accessible :user_attributes 

end
```

ManualSubscription inherits from Subscription and in Subscription model

```
belongs_to :user
```

I am building the user model through subscription because of some other reason.

in my rails console I did these

```
@subscription = TrialSubscription.new
@user = @subscription.build_user(email: "helloworld@gmail.com", password: "thisiseightcharacters")
@subscription.save
```

I am able to create a user and its associated trial subscription at the same time. I am trying to reproduce this in the controller and the content will be user inputted.

This is my form in

app/views/trial_subscriptions/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @subscription.user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I added

```
resources :trial_subscriptions
```

so the url is `trial_subscriptions/new`

this is my controller

```
class TrialSubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end 

    def new
        @subscription = TrialSubscription.new
        @subscription.build_user 
    end 

    def create
        @subscription = TrialSubscription.new(params[:subscription])
        @subscription.email = :email
        @subscription.password = :password
        if @subscription.save 
            flash[:notice] = "Trial Subscription has started"
        else
            flash[:error] = "There was an error creating this subscription, please try again"
        end 
    end 
end
```

1) What is happening between new and create?

2) in my create method the params[:subscription] is pointing to the  @subscription object in my form is this correct?

3) The :email is actually user attribute, is it getting passed correctly at @subscription.email = :email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new action looks correct, your create action needs some update.  Let's first start from your association then move on to the form and then to your `create` action.

In the form view code, you are building a form for `@subscription.user`.  The `simple_form_for` method would translate this to `create` action in `UsersController`.  But you do not have this and your intention is to create `user` through `TrialSubscriptionsController`.

So in order to make this happen, you need to change the form so that when it renders and/or submits it creates the form for `trial_subscription` along with the defined `user_attributes` within `trial_subscription`.  So, update your view to:

```
<%= simple_form_for @subscription do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :user do |u| %>
    <%= u.input :email %>
    <%= u.input :password %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The changes are `simple_form_for @subscription.user` to `simple_form_for @subscription`, and wrapping `email` and `password` fields with `f.simple_fields_for :user`.  With these changes, when your form submits, it will execute the `create` action of the `TrialSubscriptionsController`.

The next change is on the `TrialSubscriptionsController#create` action.

```
def create
    @subscription = TrialSubscription.new(params[:trial_subscription])
    if @subscription.save 
        flash[:notice] = "Trial Subscription has started"
    else
        flash[:error] = "There was an error creating this subscription, please try again"
    end 
end
```

The changes here are `@subscription = TrialSubscription.new(params[:subscription])` to `@subscripition = TrialSubscription.new(params[:trial_subscription])`, this is because your object is of type `TrialSubscription` not `Subscription`.

The second change is removal of the following lines:

```
@subscription.email = :email
@subscription.password = :password
```

This is because, as you say, `email` and `password` are members of `user` not `trial_subscription`.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: if I want to have set values for a field in simple_form, do you know of a way? there is a field :expiration_time (datetime) in subscription that I need to set for 2 weeks only. If I do a `f.input` in simple_form the user can set its own time?

Comment: Yes, doing `f.input :expiration_time` would do it.

Comment: no because simple_form will output a calendar for the user to choose a date (because it sees the datetime type) , I only want to set it within a 2 week period to cancel the trial when time is up.

Comment: I see what you mean, I did not pay attention to the "2 weeks only" part.  I assumed your comment was more so to include the date field for `trial_subscription`.  If your requirement is to set this date yourself rather than have user select, you could do this in a `after_save` callback.  Or better have all `trial_subscription` initialize with `2 weeks expiration date` by adding a callback `after_initialize` on `trial_subscription` model.

Comment: do you have time for one more question?